# Eclipse Class Editor Formatting

Tags: eclipse, class, ide

Eclipse's class editor has no formatting or collapsable fields / methods. How can I make the class editor have the same text formatting as the java editor? Or at least make it more readable and user friendly, such as the one in Netbeans.

Opening a class in Netbeans:
[image: Netbeans Class Editor]

Opening a class in ECLIPSE:
[image: Eclipse Class Editor]

I would like to make classes more readable in Eclipse, is there any way to do that? I have tried attaching a source / javadocs before with no luck. I am hoping there is a simpler way

Comment: The "Class File Editor" does not show you source. This question doesn't make sense.

Comment: Basically I want the Class Editor to be more readable and user friendly, like the one in Netbeans.

Comment: @nitind I updated the question, hopefully it is more clear

Comment: You have to tell Eclipse where the source code of the class is (using the Attach Source button)

Answer (score 0):

You want to see a source like representation of a .class file. Although not exactly what you are looking for [JD-Eclipse](http://jd.benow.ca/) can be used for that purpose. Addmitedly the scope is broader, because it is a full blown decompiler, that will actually show you the code, but should work for you.

When installed it will by default open .class files and present the code instead of default view that only presents somewhat raw results of parsing bytecode.

Another option is [Bytecode Outline](http://andrei.gmxhome.de/bytecode/) that is not a decompiler, it only deassemples bytecodes in the editor, but can make debugging a bit easier, because it seems to handle line numbers in sync with the debugger, unlike JD-Eclipse, which just outputs line number comments.